# JavaScript avoid bad words in textarea by using an alert box?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a script which can check my textarea if there are any bad words in there. Once the users leaves the textarea their should be alert box appearing. After that the inputted text in the area should be deleted.

I need JavaScript solutions (no jQuery please).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>RIC</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <textarea name="ric" id="textarea">
            </textarea>

            <script>

                my_textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

                if (/\b(?=\w)(asshole|fucking)\b(?!\w)/i.test(my_textarea.value)) {
                    alert("Hey no bad words here!");
                } else {
                    // Okay move on!
                }

            </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: get the value of the textarea using `document.getElementById("textarea");` and find out the index of the bad words you are talking about. If index is greater than 0 mean it includes bad words. alert the user.

Comment: Whats wrong with your solution?

Comment: When I actually leave the textarea no alert box appears . After that the text in the textarea should be deleted.

Comment: @viveksinghggits so actually you mean I have to make an array with the bad words and then check if the index is greater than 0. After that there should be an alert box appearing. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes,it can be done if there are a lot of words you want to filter out.

Comment: you should add 'g' flag to your regexp, using it, you will be able to to something like this : textarea.value = value.replace(regexp, '')

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you can do. First create a function which will check for invalid words and clear the textarea:

```
function filterTextarea() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
  var matches = textarea.value.match(<THE REGEX FOR THE WORDS YOU WANT TO FILTER>);

  if (matches) {
    alert('Hey, no bad words!');
    textarea.value = '';
    return;
  }

  // Other stuff.
}
```

Then attach an event listener to the textarea, which will check it every time a key is pressed and pass your function as a callback.

```
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('keyup', filterTextarea, false);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll get an `alert` for each key as the user deletes the bad words and moves their cursor around.

Comment: Actually, what this will do (and what the asker requested) is clear the textarea. So if a bad word is detected, the whole text will be deleted. Not saying it's a good idea or UX, but it was what was being asked.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. It will also censor the words by replacing them with a group of asterisk characters.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RIC</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <textarea name="ric" id="textarea" onblur="checkWords()"></textarea>
    
    <script>
      function checkWords() {
        var my_textarea = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
        var pattern = /fox|dog/ig;
        
        if (my_textarea.match(pattern)) {
          alert("Hey no bad words here!");
          my_textarea = my_textarea.replace(pattern, "****" );
          document.getElementById('textarea').value = my_textarea;
        }
        
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function does not get called (well it does get called, once at page load) is because there is no event handler to check when the user leaves the text area. You can either use `onChange` or `onBlur` they both trigger when the user leaves but `onChange` will only trigger when the content has actually been changed.

Try changing your code to this:

```
        <textarea name="ric" id="textarea" onBlur="check()">


        </textarea>

                <script>
                var check = function(){
                my_textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

                    if (/\b(?=\w)(asshole|fucking)\b(?!\w)/i.test(my_textarea.value)) {
                        alert("Hey no bad words here!");
                        my_textarea.value = "";
                    } else {
                        // Okay move on!
                    }}
                </script>
```

As for the checking on bad words, as stated by others you can loop an array of 'bad words' with `<text>.indexOf(<bad word>)` and check if the index is found or not. There might be a 'nicer' way using regex but can't help with that

Comment: Your comment explains why onchange is better but you still went with onblur?

Comment: My comment just stated the difference. I don't have a specific reason for using onBlur instead of onChange, i guess it depends on the situation.

Comment: Yes, why would you validate something if it hasn't changed?

Comment: No idea. This is just a quick snippet and onBlur came to mind before onChange. I wrote the comment after the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my code,Please do populate the badword array with your bad words and this code must oppose bad words ,it will.!!!

```
        <div>
            <textarea name="ric" id="txtArea" onkeyup="badWordChecker()" onblur="nothingTyped()"> </textarea>
        </div>
        <script>
            function nothingTyped() {
                var badWordTextBoxLength = document.getElementById('txtArea').value.length;

                if (badWordTextBoxLength == 0) {
                    alert("YOu cannot leave easily!!!Please type something ");
                    document.getElementById('txtArea').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function badWordChecker() {
                //create an array of bad words
                var badwords = ["f***", "a****", "f***"];
                var badWordTextBox = document.getElementById('txtArea');
                var badWordTextBoxValue = badWordTextBox.innerText;
                var backgroundcolor = "white";

                function isTheWordBad(value, index, array) {
                    if (value == badWordTextBoxValue) {
                        alert("hey!No badwords");
                        badWordTextBox.textContent = "";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {                    
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                var result = badwords.filter(isTheWordBad);
            }
        </script>
</body>
```